# Admin react Autocomplete in filter

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, react-admin

How to use autocomplete component from material UI, as a filter on the list to filter data of Datagrid? I need an example to do this.
I need to control the data in DataGrid according to what I chose in the combo.
Form Example:
[image]

Comment: I would start taking a look at https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/. I hope this helps!

Comment: I need filter the DataGrid according where Combobox result, i has update my question with example form.

Answer (score 0):

Material UI Autocomplete works well with React Hooks too:

https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

I created this sandbox, which contains Autocomplete for both Single Select and Multi-select with filtering values in Graph:

https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-simple-chart-w525v?file=/demo.jsx